# Create a div when text dragged from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

my problem is the following:
- I have a textarea filled up with some content
- I'd like to select a part of it, create a transient box around the selected text and drag it to a defined place (div, or something)
- I also want to modify the selected part in the original text.

Here's a basic drawing about that:

[image: Basic drawing about my problem]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

- Get the current document text `selection`
- Create some **click+drag event** that activates if there's a selection
- Hard you'll be able to **strike-out** a text if you don't use `contenteditable`
- **Show a box** that will appear near the cursor and **fill with text** from selection
- On `mousemove` use event.pageX, pageY to make the DIV **follow your mouse**
- on `mouseup` **hide** that floating element and clear it's content
- **append the text** to the element that is currently hovered

Hell of a work to write the code for you, but use Goog and follow this steps